# In SQL, a Join is actually an Intersection? And it is also a linkage or a "Sideway Union"?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, union, intersection

I always thought of a Join in SQL as some kind of linkage between two tables.

For example,

```
select e.name, d.name from employees e, departments d 
  where employees.deptID = departments.deptID
```

In this case, it is linking two tables, to show each employee with a department name instead of a department ID.  And kind of like a "linkage" or "Union" sideway".

But, after learning about inner join vs outer join, it shows that a Join (Inner join) is actually an intersection.

For example, when one table has the ID 1, 2, 7, 8, while another table has the ID 7 and 8 only, the way we get the intersection is:

```
select * from t1, t2 where t1.ID = t2.ID
```

to get the two records of "7 and 8".  So it is actually an intersection.

So we have the "Intersection" of 2 tables.  Compare this with the "Union" operation on 2 tables.  Can a Join be thought of as an "Intersection"?  But what about the "linking" or "sideway union" aspect of it?

Answer (score 8):

You're on the right track; the rows returned by an `INNER JOIN` are those that satisfy the join conditions.  But this is like an intersection only because you're using *equality* in your join condition, applied to columns from each table.

Also be aware that `INTERSECTION` is already an SQL operation and it has another meaning -- and it's not the same as `JOIN`.

An SQL `JOIN` can produce a new type of row, which has all the columns from both joined tables.  For example: col4, col5, and col6 don't exist in table A, but they do exist in the result of a join with table B:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5, b.col6
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON a.col2=b.col5;
```

An SQL `INTERSECTION` returns rows that are common to two separate tables, which must already have the *same* columns.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM A
INTERSECT
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM B;
```

This happens to produce the same result as the following join:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON a.col1=b.col1 AND a.col2=b.col2 AND a.col3=b.col3;
```

Not every brand of database supports the `INTERSECTION` operator.

Answer (score 2):

A join 'links' or erm... joins the rows from two tables. I think that's what you mean by 'sideways union' although I personally think that is a terrible way to phrase it. But there are different types of joins that do slightly different things:

- An inner join is indeed an intersection.
- A full outer join is a union.

This [page](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) on Jeff Atwood's blog describes other possibilities.

Comment: say, if both tables have all matching deptIDs, so the two tables merged side by side, in that sense it is like a "sideway union"

Comment: @Jian Lin: If it makes it easier for you to think of it as a 'sideways union' then fine, but union has a well defined meaning in SQL and it is not that. I would avoid using that term when talking to other people.

Answer (score 0):

An Outer Join  - is not related to  - Union or Union All.

For example, a 'null' would not occur as a result of Union or Union All operation, but it results from an Outer Join.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` treats two `NULL`s as two different values. So, if you join based on a nullable column, and if both tables have `NULL` values in that column, then `INNER JOIN` will ignore those rows.

Therefore, to correctly retrieve all common rows between two tables, `INTERSECT` should be used. `INTERSECT` treats two `NULL`s as the same value.

**Example(SQLite):**

Create two tables with nullable columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT, firstName TEXT);
CREATE TABLE Table2 (id INT, firstName TEXT);
```

Insert `NULL` values:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, NULL);
```

Retrieve common rows using `INNER JOIN` (This shows no output):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON 
    Table1.id=Table2.id AND Table1.firstName=Table2.firstName;
```

Retrieve common rows using `INTERSECT` (This correctly shows the common row):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

**Conclusion:**

Even though, many times both `INTERSECT` and `INNER JOIN` can be used to get the [same results](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/03/sql-server-2005-difference-between-intersect-and-inner-join-intersect-vs-inner-join/), they are not the same and should be picked depending on the situation.